# Error handling within Foreach-object Parallel block - Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, foreach-object

What would be the best way to capture error within below Foreach-Object Parallel block as there would be three separate threads/runspaces running and executing code written in the block and multiple errors/exception can occurs at the same time? Would it be possible to capture all the errors in a list/variable and show at the end of the execution of the script?

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 3 -Parallel  {
            #Some code here that throws error                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The -ErrorVariable param will give you an arraylist of ErrorRecords at the end:

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 3 -Parallel {
    throw "Item $_ Error"
} -ErrorVariable allErrors
```